# if folder name contains date

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do checks on the selected folder in PowerShell forms. 
If I don't do the check then date gets added multiple times.

```
$SelUser = $objListBox.SelectedItem
$SelUserPath = "c:\Users\$SelUser" 

If $SelUserPath Name contains a DATE
Then stop
Else Rename-Item $SelUserPath -NewName "$($SelUserPath)_$(Get-Date -F dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm)$($_.Extension)"
```

Comment: `if ($SelUser -notmatch '\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}_\d{2}-\d{2}') { Rename-Item ... }`

Comment: nice work Ansgar. I can see that it matches the date format to dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm but if the date is in a different format?

Comment: ok, just added '_'  I think that this should do for me because I think won't have user folder with _. There is good link for this matter. http://powershellcookbook.com/recipe/qAxK/appendix-b-regular-expression-reference

Comment: For matching different date formats you'll need different patterns, obviously. You can define them in a single regular expression, though, as an [alternation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions).